# Golang Private Registry on Disk cannot read pushed images

Tags: go, containers

I created a container private registry using golang (this one: `https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/pkg/registry/blobs_disk_test.go`)

I added it to push all images not in memory but on disk

My question is, is it there a way to read all images already pushed on the disk if I'll open again the registry.
Right now, I'm pusing images to disk, close the registry and open it again ... it will not see images pushed before, I'll need to push them again ...

So the question is if there is a solution to first read all pushed images when the registry is open again

Regards,